# Java object with a "generic" field

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have started to learn Java and Spring MVC. Bellow is a fragment from one of my "project".

**WelcomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    private static final String LOGIN_PAGE="/login"; 


    @Autowired
    private ViewsService templateService;


    @RequestMapping(value =WelcomeController.LOGIN_PAGE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginData(Model model) throws PageNotFoundException {
        ViewData viewData =templateService.getViewData(WelcomeController.LOGIN_PAGE,"");
        viewData.setForm(new LoginForm());
        model.addAttribute("view", viewMetaData);   
        return viewData.getViewName();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = WelcomeController.LOGIN_PAGE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postLoginData(Model model, HttpSession session, ViewData viewData) {
        System.out.println(viewData);
        System.out.println(viewData.getForm());

    }
}
```

The folowing class will be used for other pages with forms but instead of LoginForm there will be different classes.
Besides having one class for every page with froms is there any other nice solution ( like one class but with one field which could accept different objects like LoginForm, SupportForm, ContactForm)?

**ViewData.java**

```
public class ViewData {

    private String viewName;
    private Map<String, String> labels;
    private LoginForm form;


    public String getViewName() {
        return viewName;
    }
    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }
    public void setLabels(Map<String, String> labels) {
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    public LoginForm getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(LoginForm form) {
        this.form = form;

    }
}
```

**LoginForm.java**

```
public class LoginForm{

    private String userCode;
    private String password;

    public String getUserCode() {
        return userCode;
    }
    public void setUserCode(String userCode) {
        this.userCode = userCode;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**Jsp Page**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" modelAttribute="view.form" htmlEscape="true" cssClass="form-signin">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userCode" class="sr-only">${view.labels['USER_NAME']}</label>
        <form:input type="input" path="userCode" id="password" placeholder="password" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="userCode" cssClass="errorMessage" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">${view.labels['USER_PASSWORD']}</label>
        <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" placeholder="password" cssClass="form-control" />
        <form:errors path="password" cssClass="errorMessage" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">OK</button>
</form:form>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the generics is not needed.

Let classes `LoginForm`, `SupportForm`, `ContactForm` implement an interface `Form`. However, a bare and naked interface (is called the *marker interface*) is not a nice usage of an interface. Enrich it by some methods, a functionality based on the current implementation if possible.

```
public class LoginForm implements Form {
    ...
}
```

Applying this the class `ViewData` would look like in the following snippet:

```
public class ViewData {

   private String viewName;
   private Map<String, String> labels;
   private Form form;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tryed this but I get the following error when I press the jsp page button "Could not instantiate property type Form to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantianException: failed to instantiate Form: Specified class is an interface."

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am afraid that I don't fully see your goal with this. Nevertheless, you can easily use generics:

```
public class ViewData<T extends DefaultForm> {

    private String viewName;
    private Map<String, String> labels;
    private T form;

    public T getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(T form) {
        this.form = form;

    }
    ...
```

The gotcha is that there shall be a common anchestor of all forms, I called this DefaultForm here:

```
public class DefaultForm {

}
```

And then inherit from that in all of your forms:

```
public class LoginForm extends DefaultForm {
...
}
```

This way, any DefaultForm descendant will work for you.

Small print: forms differ, they have different attributes, inputs, whatever. Storing them this way treats all forms as if it would be a DefaultForm, so the actual real life value of this solution is questionable.